# Is there any difference in HBase performance when a value is used as column name?

Tags: hbase

In HBase, is there any difference in performance or any other aspects when I store a value in a column or use the value itself as the column name?

ex:

```
<table>:<Column-Family>:<Column-Name>=<value>
vs
<table>:<Column-Family>:<Column-Name>:<value>=1
```

What's recommended to use in what scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on data and what you need to extract from it! If you're having a database with a list of equipments and their associated sensors like this :

> ID - LABEL - SENSORS
>
> 1 - K200 - 1,2
> 2 - K300 - 1,2,3
>
> ID - LABEL - SENSOR_1 - SENSOR_2 - SENSOR_3
>
> 1 - K200 - 1 - 1 - 0
> 2 - K300 - 1 - 1 - 1

In my opinion the first design is better, you don't have to store the 0 unlike the second design, but it depends on what information you need to extract. If you just want to check which equipment is integrating a SENSOR TYPE 1 the second design is better because you're going to read a column on each row whereas with the first design you'll have to process data ... But if you're just asking what type of sensor is available for each equipment the first design is better ... Try to list what you need to know from your data and according to this you can think about the design !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the table design and necessity, the more general purpose
`<table>:<Column-Family>:<Column-Name>=<value>`
is more commonly used for general purpose storage, but in some cases
`<table>:<Column-Family>:<Column-Name>:<value>=1`
can be more fitting to the scenario like:
- you need to filter the value together with the column name
- you want to have a column with multiple value, and avoiding serialization
- you need to check whether a column has a specific value very often very fast
there are much more cases that can profit from the later design, but once again it's back to what you need